# How can I easily make a new Word macro out of an old one?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an old word macro written in Visual Basic and made in 2003 that is used for formatting articles in a certain way—makes special headings, creates table of contents, formats footnotes in a specific way, etc. Unfortunately, it does not work on versions of Word past Windows 2010. I am surprised that it made it that far. I have programming experience in other languages and have used Visual Basic for Excel many years ago so I feel like I could possibly fix it on my own (maybe I'm being a little too optimistic), but I have zero experience with Visual Basic on Word so I was wondering if there is an easy way to convert an older Word macro into one that will work with newer versions of Word. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Without being able to see the code? Maybe you can include the relevant part of it that gives you a specific problem in your question?

Comment: .doc and .docx are basically different, maybe this is the point. I maybe can rewrite the code, however, I can't rewrite without the source. Maybe you just want a facility to transform the old code into the new one.

Comment: The VBA object model has changed comparatively little from 2003 to 2010. Adapted your existing code should not be too difficult, but you would have to post it, along with the exact wording of any error messages and which line raises them.